# Extract 2 fields from 2 different lines

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have the below lines in my file

```
# Employee Id  : ABC123,
# Employee Name: Vivek
# Employee Type: Temp                     Join Date: 31-jan-2014  Buz Code: 2098
# Employee Comments: 
#              Replacement for Jane
#   Country: India
#   State: Delhi
#
# Employee Id  : GGG67,
# Employee Name: Kumar
# Employee Type: Temp                     Join Date:15-jan-2014  Buz Code: 2176
# Employee Comments: 
#   Country: India
#   State: Delhi
#   Street: Kanot
```

From this, I need `Employee ID`, `Employee Name` and `Buz Code` in a table format for all employees. I tried with `awk`, but no results as expected.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem less like a homework assignment if you showed what you've already tried.  That said, here's a start - you need to grab the fields by matching on the field names, but not output them until you hit the next record. It would be convenient if there's a "#" between all records as you show...

```
$ awk -F: -f t.awk t
 ABC123,  Vivek
 GGG67,  Kumar
```

It's helpful with longer awk scripts to store them in a separate file

```
$ cat t.awk
/Employee Id/ {empid=$2}
/Employee Name/ {name=$2}
/#/ {print empid, name} # What happens if the next record is missing name?
END {print empid, name}
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
$ awk -F: '/Employee Id/ {empid=$2}; /Employee Name/ {name=$2}; /#/ {print empid, name}; END {print empid, name}' t
```

Comment: Hi Ian, Thanks for the one liner. I tried `cat sample.txt | sed -n '/##     EMPLOYEE DETAILS/,$p' | awk  -F"" '/^# Employee Name:/{print $4;next}{print $10}'`

Comment: You're welcome.  I see the question has been edited to use a different format (there is a # sign at the front of every line).  Is that the actual format?  Does this concept make sense now - grab the piece you need from each line, and don't output until the next record?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{printf /Employee Id|Employee Name|Buz Code/? $NF" " : " "}' file
```

Prints last field `$NF` if found any pattern that matched like `Employee Id` or`|` ...
else`?` print single space`" "`.

Result in column order:

```
ABC123, Vivek 2098      GGG67, Kumar 2176
```

---

OR

```
awk '/Employee Id|Employee Name|Buz Code/ {if(++i%4==0) printf RS;printf $NF FS }' file
```

Note that `RS` means newline`\n` and `FS` means single space(by default).

Result in row order:

```
ABC123, Vivek 2098
GGG67, Kumar 2176
```

Comment: You are welcome. @VivekKumar.K please [mark one of answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) as accepted which is worked for your asked question. thank you and if you have new question please open it as new one.